# What is this "RecyclerView has no LayoutManager androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView" error?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase. But it shows "RecyclerView has no LayoutManager androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView" error? Can somebody help me to fix this error please?
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g11kr.png)

NewsAdapter.java

```
private List<NewsModel> newsModels;

    public NewsAdapter( List<NewsModel> newsModels) {
        this.newsModels = newsModels;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news,parent,false);
        return new NewsViewHolder (view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NewsModel news = newsModels.get(position);

        holder.textViewName.setText(news.getName());
        holder.textViewBrand.setText(news.getBrand());
        holder.textViewDesc.setText(news.getDescription());
        holder.textViewPrice.setText("INR " + news.getPrice());
        holder.textViewQty.setText("Available Units: " + news.getQty());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newsModels.size();
    }

    class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewName, textViewBrand, textViewDesc, textViewPrice, textViewQty;

        public NewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_name);
            textViewBrand = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_brand);
            textViewDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_desc);
            textViewPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_price);
            textViewQty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_quantity);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please do not show picture of text.  Copy the text into the question so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: where is the adpter and layoutmanger implementation. as the error says there is no layoutmanger attached to the recyclerview. just add a recycerview to it and rerun the code

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm sorry. I'm new here. Thank you for your advice

Comment: @Harkal Should I implement it inside NewsViewHolder?

Comment: you have to do it before setting the adapter

Comment: who you want your view to be ? vertical or horizontal ?

Comment: @Harkal vertical

Comment: @MrKaV look at the answer i have posted you have to add two properties to your recyclerview in your xml code i.e. `layoutManager` and `orientation`

Comment: Please edit the question to remove the image and copy the text into it.  There is an edit link at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you haven't added a recycler view then you could just add it through xml code like this

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
 android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: @MrKaV i m glad ;)

Answer (score 0):

in your activity that you want use recyclerView:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView  =   findViewById(R.id.recyclerVeiw);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setAdapter(new YourAdapeter());
```